# Is it possible to execute scripts on BigQuery in Dataflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two tables: one table with data to process and a tracking table that keeps track of the data that's already been processed.

So for example, the tracking table below would indicate that we've already processed data from those two days.

```
date
---
3/15/23
3/16/23
```

If I were just running it directly in BigQuery or another database, I would do something like this (in pseudocode)

```
last_processed_date = max(date) from tracking table
date_to_process = last_processed_date + 1

select * from main table where date = date_to_process

insert into tracking table values(date_to_process)
```

The issue is that since this is a "script" and not a single expression, I don't think I can run it using the BigQueryIO connector using Dataflow. I'm wondering if there's something that I'm missing that would make this possible.

Comment: Do you use an orchestration tool like Airflow with Dataflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1 :

If it's possible, find a way to apply the needed logic for input fully in `SQL`, with a solution that looks like :

```sql
select * from main table where date = 
  select increment_date(maxDate) 
  from 
     (select max(date) as maxDate from tracking table);
```

Then pass the inputs to your `Dataflow` job.

#### Solution 2 :

If the solution 1 is not possibe, I think it's better to execute the first 2 queries outside of `Dataflow` :

```
last_processed_date = max(date) from tracking table
date_to_process = last_processed_date + 1
```

Then pass `date_to_process` as a pipeline option to the `Dataflow` job.

In your job, your input connector would be a `BigQueryIO.read` that executes the following query by the date argument :

```sql
select * from main table where date = date_to_process
```

The output connector would be a `BigQuery.write`.

You can create a `Shell` script using `gcloud` cli and `bq` to execute the first query and increment the value.

Then launch the `Dataflow` job with the previous calculated date.

Example :

```bash
# Execute the first query
last_processed_date="bq query --quiet --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECCT max(date) from tracking table' | awk '{if(NR>1)print}'"

date_to_process=$((++last_processed_date))

# Launch the Dataflow job, example with Python
python -m your_folder.main \
        --runner=DataflowRunner \
        --region=europe-west1 \
        --date_to_process=$date_to_process \
       ....
```

#### Solution 3 :

The same as solution 2 but with `Airflow`.

If you are using a pipeline orchestrator like `Airflow` in your project, you can apply the same logic presented in the solution 2, but with Python code and operators

```
- A first operator BigQueryInsertJobOperator that executes query, get the result and pass it with xcom to a second operator
- The second operator BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator that launches the Dataflow job and passing the date as pipeline argument
```

Comment: That makes sense, I’ve been moving towards this conclusion myself but was hoping that there’d be an elegant way around it. I took a look at Dataflow flex templates; have you seen them being used for something like this before?

Comment: Dataflow Flex Template is a way to standardize the deployment of Dataflow jobs. There are also default templates, but I the problematic is the same.

Comment: I edited my answer to propose you also another solution and approach (solution 1 fully in SQL for input). I hope it helps.

Comment: I think your second solution might be the only option. The first solution is actually what I tried first, but the problem is that it’s not easy to also update the tracking table afterwards (to show that the date has been processed)

Comment: Ok I understand, may you upvote the answer to make it more valuable please ?

Answer (score 0):

one possible option is dataflow sql jobs - see here

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/parameterized-queries#using_timestamps_in_parameterized_queries

The job can be callable from your main dataflow, programmatically too, also see this

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/parameterized-queries#using_timestamps_in_parameterized_queries

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. Do parameterized queries work for BigQuery sql expressions as well?

Comment: Hi there, not exactly all of bigquery sql expressions. see this for detailed list of supported dataflow sql query syntax https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/sql/query-syntax - If you can give me the exact query you want to run from dataflow, I can try and provide answer to with dataflow sql query syntax. hope this helped

Comment: That’s a great link. My query is just the one listed above, selecting from the table where the date is a certain date.